# 'At the weekend' or 'At weekends' for regular occurence

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Which sentence is correct?

> I go running at the weekend.
>   I go running at weekends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In American English you would say:

> I go running on weekends.
>
> Weekends I go running.

if you wanted to say that it is your practice to run every weekend; or

> I am going running this weekend.

if you wanted to say that you have plans for this upcoming weekend.